# Mongo not opening connections in Spring 4 Java API

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I have an API we wrote using Spring 4 with a Mongo database.  When the application loads into my local WAS, I can see the app will go out and connect to the database.  However when I go to execute a function that should open a query, I get socket closed error.

My Configuration:

```
@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
    logger.info("loading MongoDBFactory bean" );
    String PROCESS_ID_MONGO_KEY = "PROCESS_ID_MONGO";

    Credentials credentials = credentialsManager().getCredentialsFor(PROCESS_ID_MONGO_KEY);

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(
            Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(PropertiesManagerUtility.getKeyValue(CollectionType.CREDENTIAL, "mongo.url"), 27017)),
            Arrays.asList(MongoCredential.createPlainCredential(credentials.getUserid(), "$external", credentials.getPassword().toCharArray())),
            MongoClientOptions.builder()
                    .sslEnabled(true).connectTimeout(30)
                    .writeConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY)
                    .socketKeepAlive(true)
                    .build());
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, PropertiesManagerUtility.getKeyValue(CollectionType.CREDENTIAL, "mongo.db"));
}
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    logger.info("loading MongoTemplate bean" );
   // MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
}
```

My Dao

```
@Component("achResponseDMDao")
public class AchResponseDMDaoImpl implements IBasicDao<AchResponseDM>{
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public AchResponseDMDaoImpl(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate){
    this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
}

@Override
public AchResponseDM findByResponseCode( String responseCode){
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("responseCode").is(responseCode));        
    return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, AchResponseDM.class);
}
...
}
```

Question is I thought Spring would give me a new connection using the MongoFactory but it appears that original connection gets closed and no more are created.  What do I need to do?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injecting the factory instead of the MongoTemplate instance created new connections as needed.  The corresponding DAOImpl would have `@Autowired MongoFactory mongoFactory;` and the method would create an instance of `new mongoTemplate(mongoFactory).find(...)` or otherwise.

the resulting DAO looks like:

```
@Component("achResponseDMDao")
public class AchResponseDMDaoImpl implements IBasicDao<AchResponseDM>{
    @Autowired
    MongoFactory mongoFactory;

@Override
public AchResponseDM findByResponseCode( String responseCode){
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("responseCode").is(responseCode));        
    List<AchResponseDM> listOfResponses = mongoTemplate(mongoFactory).find(query, AchResponseDM.class);
    return (listOfResponses!=null && !listOfResponses.isEmpty())?listOfResponses.get(0):defaultNonNullResponse();
}
...
}
```